# Get the HTTP request in CORS policy in ASP.net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, .net-6.0

I'm writing a web application with .NET 6 and I have the requirement of allowing cross origin requests from certain domains. .NET allows this by providing the `AddCors` method, which you can configure with something like this:

```
services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("policy_name", policyBuilder =>
{
    policyBuilder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin =>
    {
        if(/* domain check logic */)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}));
```

However, I have a problem: there are certain endpoints in my app where I need to check the value of a certain header of the request in order to decide if the origin is allowed or not.

The problem is that in the `SetIsOriginAllowed` method I only have the origin as a string, I don't have the entire request. Is there a way to get the request when deciding if an origin is allowed?

FURTHER EXPLANATION ON WHY I NEED THIS: the app I'm developing is multi-tenant, meaning users from multiple organizations can call my app's APIs from their organization's domain. I need to allow the cross origin request from a certain domain only if the request is for the tenant associated to that domain. To do this, I need to read the request (there is an HTTP header in the request that specifies the tenant)

Answer (score 1):

Just the `SetIsOriginAllowed()` server is not send the 'Vary' header. Maybe you should make this things "Allow Any Origin" in your cors policy something like

`SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)`

**UPDATE**

So you want to developing a multi-tenant application, you can follow like:-

```
services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("policy_name", policyBuilder =>
{
    policyBuilder.SetIsOriginAllowed(IsOriginAllowed)
    .WithOrigins(corsOriginAllowed);
 
}));
```

`IsOriginAllowed` Function:-

```
private static bool IsOriginAllowed(string host)
{
    var corsOriginAllowed = new[] { "teacher.com", "student.com","others.com" };

    return corsOriginAllowed.Any(origin =>
        Regex.IsMatch(host, $@"^http(s)?://.*{origin}(:[0-9]+)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Making it always true exposes the API to CORS-based attacks though, it's not a solution, it's just ignoring the problem

Comment: @Master_T  I updated answer.please check.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I understand that I can check a list of values to see if the origin is allowed. however it doesn't really answer my question: I wanted to know if you can access the HTTP request from the `IsOriginAllowed` method. I guess it isn't possible?

Comment: @Master_T Maybe it's possible using HttpContext.